# 3D Manipulator only selects a handful of times

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I have tried [this fix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101959/i-cant-use-the-3d-manipulator) and it did fix my problem.

I have noticed one thing as I've been trying to get the 3D manipulator to work. It is that everything has the manipulator at the a place other then the center of the object. I don't know if that is what is causing the issue but it did seem strange and worth mentioning.

Another strange this is that when I am able to select an arrow it moves in the wrong direction. In the picture included I am trying to brag the x axis and when finally grabbed it moves in the 7 axis.

[image: Here] is my screen shot I think everything needed is in the picture. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the 3d-manipulator questions [this helped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90438/3d-manipulators-unselectable-while-lock-to-cursor-is-turned-on) me find the solution.

It turns out I somehow locked my objects to another object. I don't know how I did it but after clearing all the objects from having an object they were locked to it fixed the problem.

My view field looks like this now:

[image: this]